# Using NodeJS module in Titanium Studio

Tags: node.js, titanium-mobile

All, I am trying to using third party NodeJS SDK in Titanium Studio. However, I consistently encounter dependency issues, such as util.js, utils.js, ms.js, events.js etc. I tried to add the missing module manually, but it looks like it will become un-tractable as there are so many dependencies.

My questions are :

```
1. Is that possible to use NodeJS based SDK in Titanium Studio . 
2. If so, what is the right approach to include the dependencies.
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What do you need to do? On Titanium Studio, NodeJS already implements some external tools, like Alloy, the recent SDK CLI (Appcelerator command-line interface) and additional products.

Comment: I am trying to use a third party SDK implemented based on NodJS. It uses the singnalR, websocket etc modules, which looks missing in Titanium Studio. Probably I didn't do it right as I just try to use "var sdk = require("sdkname");" to include the SDK.

Comment: I'm not following you. _"var sdk = require("sdkname");"_ is meant to load a CommonJS module (either native android, iOS or Javascript) that can be used within your app. e.g. http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/api/Global-method-require

You should add more details about the _third party SDK_ you wanted to include (include logs, links and why not actual NodeJS packages to be able to replicate).

Comment: Thanks for your comment! The SDK I am trying to use is mojio-js. Here is the link "https://github.com/mojio/mojio-js". It relies on SingnalR and other NodeJS environment. Thanks.

Comment: Gotcha. I have an slight idea how you could get it to work. Will add a few notes shortly.

Answer (score 0):

Titanium can't get Coffee scripts to work natively (assuming you want to deploy the  [TitaniumWrapper.coffee](https://github.com/mojio/mojio-js/tree/master/src/titanium)). A possible solution you may want to try is hooking a plugin  http://billdawson.com/titanium_coffee_script/ in order to pre-compile Coffee scripts.

You can also try to embed everything using a Tiwebview that wraps [HTML](https://github.com/mojio/mojio-js/blob/master/example/login.html) to load mojio-js.js but you would still need to observe events mojio client (like replacing keys, login an user and create a few model instances).

Hope you find the info useful and can serve for further research.

Comment: Thank you very much! I will give it a try and post my update later.

Comment: Probably I missed something, but I don't think I actually need coffee scripts to work as the mojio SDK has the javascript codes. My problem is that it relies on some NodeJS modules which are either missing or not supported in Titanium.